# Flex-basis calculation possible?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to calculate the flexbox flex-basis property?

Something like this

> flex-basis: 20%-30px

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, and you use [CSS Calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

*Note, there need to be space before/after the minus sign `-`.*

```
flex-basis: calc(20% - 30px);
```

Comment: space b/w `-` is important

Comment: thanks works perfect...yeah i noticed to that space is very important wrote it without at first and it didnt work

Comment: yes as long as you are not dealing with IE.. 

better read this for a solution that works everywhere 

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/can-calc-be-used-for-a-flex-basis-value

Comment: @AshishSajwan If one use the longhand `flex-basis`, CSS `calc()` work with IE as well